# Using `history.replace` with Angular 1.x

Tags: angular-routing, html5-history, angularjs-ng-route, angularjs

I need help using `history.replaceState` on an Angular 1.x app.

My Chrome extension interacts with someone else’s app, and I want to load a Url in that app with an extra query parameter that my extension can read, and then use `history.replaceState` to remove from the url.

- Step 1: open `www.otherapp.com?extensionToken=MhtkWGUyS#/settings`
- Step 2: read `xtensionToken=MhtkWGUyS`
- Step 3: replace/remove token with `replaceState` to `www.otherapp.com#/settings`

The trouble is that Angular 1.x doesn’t like history.replaceState to be used on its own: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3789

Angular seems to revert my update back to the original Url, or scramble the Url altogether. Does anyone have experience using `history.replaceState` with an Angular app?

One solution I thought of was to use Angular’s `$location` to make the state-change, but I’m don’t know how to access `$location` outside of the Angular scope. Does anyone know how I might access that?

The tricky part of generating a reference to `$location` is that my code will run with many different apps, with their own unique angular `ng-` elements, and I don’t know what those elements are on the page. I can assume that most have Angular at `window.angular`, but I can’t easily assume what the Angular app element will be for each page.